# Blazor server web app deployed to Azure App Service effectively uses LocalDB

Tags: azure, localdb

I created a blazor server web app in Visual Studio 2022 from template that uses a default localdb database for MS identity/authentication. I deployed the app to Azure app service and it works great even with the localdb. How does that work? Does it work because it's blazor server and it just creates the localdb on whatever server it lands on? Obviously, I can get at the identity database through code, but there's no way to do SQL queries in the portal because the localdb database is "ephemeral". Can anyone help me understand how this works?

Comment: Please share your connection string

Comment: Connection string: Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet-53bc9b9d-9d6a-45d4-8429-2a2761773502;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true